# Dynamic pages through view

Tags: views

I need to create dynamic page using `Views`.
I created many of static page using `views`, for this simply define page link in view, but when I create `Dynamic page` like `'practice-areas/%'` then it is not working. Here `%` is using for `node id`.

Answer (score 1):

All the pages should share the common path like 
www.domainName.com/practice-areas/1
www.domainName.com/practice-areas/2
www.domainName.com/practice-areas/3

Like if we need to display a particular block on these URLs then we will write

practice-areas/*

Similarly % will only work if there is a common path.

Thanks.

Comment: While giving `*` in url, it show "Page not found" error. I already tried it.

Comment: Are you giving www.domainName.com/practice-areas/* ??

Comment: Yes, same as www.domainName.com/practice-areas/* in `view`

Comment: You cannot use * in views page link you have to use %.

It would be better if you export your view and paste the code here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using views arguments check this [video](http://gotdrupal.com/videos/drupal-views-arguments) to explain about drupal views arguments, using arguments in views we can create dynamic views of 'page' type display.

Answer (score 0):

You can use contextual filter in views which will pass the argument nid for your path. path will be "practice-areas/%" and for "%" you can set argument nid in contextual filter and set Content id from the URL. So it will work as per your requirement.